# Widget does not display on IOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I have a web app that allows the user to embed quoting widget's on their own personal websites. The widget is built in our app and then we give them a piece of JS that they can embed wherever they please. Example embed code:

```
<script src="https://pinney.dataraptor.com/quoting/widget/widgets/18.js"></script>
```

The issue here is that on any mobile device (Tested on IOS and Android) the widget simply won't render. I've tested on my android phone in Chrome, Firefox and IE and interestingly enough it does show in the IE app but not the others.

To see for yourself fire up http://www.wholesaleinsurance.net on a mobile device.

Comment: Well I have same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

After some exploring we found that our SSL was improperly configured, so the user had to visit and trust our sites content before the widgets would render elsewhere.